# Python works when called using python or python3 but not found using full path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm starting to work with python and running into an issue where scripts will     execute fine in terminal when called with **python**, **py**, or **python3*** but when trying to execute directly through the web or via cron with full paths, it constantly produces an error saying;

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Below are the results when running various commands

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

which python2
/usr/bin/python2

which python3
/usr/bin/python3

which python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python3.8



# ls /bin/ | grep python
abrt-action-analyze-python
python
python2
python2.7
python2.7-config
python2-config
python3
python3.6
python3.6m
python-config


# echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'
/root/.yarn/bin
/root/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/opt/cpanel/composer/bin
/root/bin
/usr/local/bin


#whereis python
python:
/usr/bin/python3.6
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.6m
/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/python
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib64/python3.6
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/etc/python /usr/local/bin/python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python3.8-config
/usr/local/lib/python3.6
/usr/local/lib/python3.8
/usr/include/python2.7
/usr/include/python3.6m
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

whereis python3
python3:
/usr/bin/python3.6 
/usr/bin/python3.6m 
/usr/bin/python3 
/usr/lib/python3.6 
/usr/lib64/python3.6 
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 
/usr/local/bin/python3 
/usr/local/bin/python3.8-config 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6 
/usr/local/lib/python3.8 
/usr/include/python3.6m 
/usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

Any advice on what to check on?

Comment: Use `type`, not `which`.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "trying to execute directly through the web"?

Comment: @Barmar 

# type python
python is /usr/bin/python

# type python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3

# type python3.8
python3.8 is /usr/local/bin/python3.8

Comment: @TimRoberts site.url/file.py (when using the python path at the top of the file) which generates Internal Server errors and the 'not found' errors in the apache error log.

Comment: Are you talking about a `#!/usr/bin/python` line at the beginning of the script?

Comment: I don't see how `which python` can print `/usr/bin/python` if that path does not exist.

Comment: I suspect there's a CRLF line ending there.

Comment: Yes.  If you copied this file from a Windows system, then it has CR/LF line endings.  The shebang `#!` lines at the beginning of the file are actually interpreted by the Linux kernel, which only understands LF endings.  Your file name would be "/usr/bin/python<CR>".

Comment: Quick question: If you follow this article. Does it still fail? https://gavinwiener.medium.com/how-to-schedule-a-python-script-cron-job-dea6cbf69f4e

Comment: @JohnGordon If `/usr/bin/python` is a symbolic link to a file that does not exist, that's exactly what you'd see.  `which` would work, but executing would get a "file not found".

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am using a windows system to develop and upload the files but linux to run.

Comment: Tell your editor to use Unix line endings, or use `dos2unix` when you upload the files to Linux.

Comment: @Barmar Still happens after running dos2unix on a hello world script.

!#/usr/bin/env python
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()
print("Hello world")

Comment: I thought you were using the absolute path, not `/usr/bin/env`

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, that was the latest attempt. Attempts with !#/usr/bin/python
!#/usr/bin/python2
!#/usr/bin/python3
!#/usr/local/bin/python3.8

all produced the same thing

Comment: If this only happens in the webserver, maybe it's running in a chroot jail that doesn't have python in it?

Comment: @Barmar Does that happen by default or special user process? This is a dedicated system and the first time to trying to run anything python beyond command line python / python3 executions.

Comment: I don't think it's the standard way webservers are configured, it's an added security.